# How to access a backbone view in another file from backbone router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I have a backbone application which works fine but was getting a bit heavy to be in one file so I have started to separate it into different files I now have:

```
backbone-view.js
backbone-router.js
...
```

I am using my backbone router to instantiate views when the URL changes like so:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'our-approach.php': 'instantiateOurApproach',
        'our-work.php': 'instantiateOurWork',
        'who-we-are.php': 'instantiateWhoWeAre',
        'social-stream.php': 'instantiateSocialStream',
        'contact.php': 'instantiateContact'
    },
    instantiateOurApproach: function() {
        if(window.our_approach_view == null) {
            window.our_approach_view = new OurApproachView();
        }
    },

    instantiateOurWork: function() {
        if(window.our_work_view == null) {
            window.our_work_view = new OurWorkView();
        }
    },

    instantiateWhoWeAre: function() {
        if(window.who_we_are_view == null) {
            window.who_we_are_view = new WhoWeAreView();
        }
    },

    instantiateSocialStream: function() {
        if(window.social_stream_view == null) {
            window.social_stream_view = new SocialStreamView();
        }
    },

    instantiateContact: function() {
        if(window.contact_view == null) {
            window.contact_view = new ContactView();
        }

    }
});
```

The problem I am now having is that I cannot access the views as they are declared in a separate file so the following are all undefined:

```
OurApproachView()
OurWorkView()
WhoWeAreView()
SocialStreamView()
ContactView()
```

I have tried doing:

```
window.OurApproachView()
```

But this doesn't work.

I am not sure what my next move is so if anyone can help that would be awesome.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

OK so it seems doing:

```
window.OurApproachView()
```

does actually work, my apologies there, but does anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take this approach:

```
// sample-view.js

var app = app || {};

$(function() {
    app.SampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#sample-element',

        template : // your template

        events: {
        // your events      
        },

        initialize: function() {
            // do stuff on initialize
        },

        render: function() {
         // do stuff on render
        }
    });
});
```

Similarly, all your js files (models, collections, routers) can be setup like this. You would then be able to access any view from the router by doing:

```
var view = new app.SampleView();
```

Comment: I like it thanks, I will give this a try. Am I right in thinking that this is the same window. but it is just a custom variable instead?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
window.our_work_view = new window.OurApproachView();
```

But I don't like it as a solution.

Anyone suggest anything better?